How do I "Use skills to reach new heights" in Hare's Nest Knoll?
One of the exploration objectives for the area Hare's Nest Knoll is to "Use skills to reach new heights".
What does this mean? How do I complete this objective?


To add to the accepted answer, I found this on Reddit:

The easiest way is to use the skill Swallow Slice aimed upwards from the highest point.
Go to the far right where there is a small ledge and then either use a swallow slice upwards from there or lure some birds over there and latch onto one to go upwards and you’ll get the achievement.


According to Supercheats,

Use your Raiment and attach yourself to one of the Sparrows and swing yourself to the top. You may need to do this a couple of times in order for the objective to complete which is using skills to reach new heights.


And take this too!

Was able to do this by heading to the innermost area, defeating enemies until Sparrows appeared, climbing up to the ledge in the top right, then jumping and attaching my Raiment to them for height until the objective was marked complete.

@Stevoisiak So the answer was correct?

Yes. I voted it up and was planning on accepting after waiting a bit for other answers.
